# Notation on measure theory

Tags: measure-theory, notation

Could somebody explain what the notation [A].[B] means in measure theory, A, B being sets, I'm cheching on an excercise relating the Radón-Nikodym derivate and it's being used that $\nu (E \cap E_i) = \int [E].[E_i] d\mu$ but I'm not sure what the notation means because it's not on the textbook I regularly follow, is this just an intersection notation? I appreciate it.

The excercise is: Let $(X, \mathcal A, \mu)$ a finite measure space, $\{E_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ a familiy of measurable sets and $\{C_k\}$ a set of real numbers, if
$$\nu(E)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty C_k \hspace{1mm} \mu (E\cap E_k)$$
I need to show $\nu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to  $\mu$ and calculate the Radon-Nikodym derivate. The absolute continuous it's quite direct  and for the second part it was being computed
$$\nu(E)=\sum_{k=1}^n C_k \mu (E\cap E_k)= \sum_{k=1}^n C_k\int [E]\cdot [E_k]d\mu = \int [E] \cdot \left(\sum_{k=1}^n C_k [E_k]\right)d\mu $$

Comment: I have never seen this, but my guess would be that for a set $S$ they denote by $[S]$ the indicator function of $S$.

Comment: At least then we would have $[E].[E_i]=[E\cap E_i]$ which would make the formula you wrote true.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: @SeverinSchraven if $\mu=\nu$.

Comment: @Alan You are right... it's too early in the morning

Comment: @Andrew Maybe you can share with us what exactly you want to show. Then we might have a better change of guessing :)

Comment: Sure! I have edited. I just didn't want to asumme what the notation was but the indicator function fits. I see I made a mistake initially writting $\nu$ instead of $\mu$, I'm sorry, Severin Schraven and Alan, you are totally right, thank you!

Comment: What book did this notation come from?

Comment: That was my issue since the book we use in class has the  $\chi _E$ notation (Folland), other books as well, but this excercise it's on a PDF with not many references and it's kind of not explained what it meant, maybe they were using their own notation.